# Why does this SQL Query not work for me?

Tags: mysql

I have some problems with an (My)SQL query. In my DB I have two tables. One is called kfz_typen, the other kfz_temp2. I need to get all entries of the kfz_temp2 table, which ktyp (just an integer field) is not in the kfz_typen table.

```
 SELECT * FROM kfz_temp2
 WHERE kfz_temp2.KType NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT kfz_typen.ktyp FROM kfz_typen)
```

In my opinion this query above should exactly do, what I want. But it doesn't! I just get an empty result back from my MySQL Server.

Without the "NOT" in the Query, I get the entries that are in both tables, so the matching does work.

So what's wrong with the Query above?

Comment: What does `select distinct kfz_typen.ktyp from kfz_typen` return on its own?

Comment: @Simon: It returns what it has to, http://nopaste.info/644154e4a4.html

Comment: @DimitriR.: Must something else. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4365d/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
SELECT t2.* FROM kfz_temp2 t2
 LEFT JOIN kfz_typen tn ON t2.KType = tn.ktyp
WHERE tn.ktyp IS NULL
```

You may need to group the result.

I'm unsure why the first query doesn't work, but I believe this does the same thing.

Comment: I agree, since this left join will return ALL kfz_typen tuples, even the tuples that are not related to kfz_temp2 (marked as NULL in kfz_typen.ktyp).

Comment: Yes, that worked for me, thx. But I still do not understand, why my first query didn't work.

Comment: The first query (with `NOT IN`) will produce zero rows if there is (even one) `NULL` in the `kfz_typen.ktyp` column. The (semantically) correct way to write this type of queries (anti-semijoins) is by using either `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` (like this answer.)

Answer (score -2):

remove distinct then i hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: Since duplicates don't affect the IN operator, removing the DISTINCT keyword would have no effect.